# Filebeats sends duplicated logs to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, filebeat

The problem is that Filebeats is sending duplicated logs to Elasticsearch, when I restart Filebeats, he sends the whole log again.

I have been mounting /var/share/filebeat/data to the container where I am runnig Filebeats. I also had change the permissions of the share directory, to be owned by the filebeats user.

I am using Elasticsearch 8.1.2

Comment: what do you mean when you say restart elasticsearch.   are you restarting filebeats or the elastic itself.   most likely reason I can think of is that the filebeats is seeing no file at some point and then the file appears (mounted?)  that looks like a log rollover probably to filebeats and it resends the data as new data.

Comment: You are right, I mean Filebeats. I edited the question.

Comment: this might help:  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/how-filebeat-works.html#_how_does_filebeat_keep_the_state_of_files

Comment: btw, if you are restarting the container you may be doing it in a way that does not preserve its file contents and that is why when it starts it resends the whole file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers, but the issue was that in the initial setup we didn't define an ID tag for the filestream input type. As simple as that.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/_step_1_set_an_identifier_for_each_filestream_input.html

Answer (score 0):

The most probable reason for this is persistent volume location for filebeat registry. Essentially, filebeat creates a registry to keep track of all log files processed and to what offset. If this registry is not stored on a persistent location (for instance stored to /tmp) and filebeat is restarted, the registry file will be lost and new one will be created. This tells filebeat to tail all the log files present at specified path from beginning, hence the duplicate logs.
To resolve this, please mount a persistent volume to filebeat (may be hostpath) and configure it to be used for storing registry.